# How do I enable word wrap in Emacs using visual-line-mode?

Tags: emacs

I have `(global-visual-line-mode t)` enabled in `.emacs`.  I'd like text to automatically wrap at column 70.

These don't work:

```
(setq-default fill-column 70)

(add-hook 'text-mode-hook
  '(lambda() (turn-on-auto-fill) (set-fill-column 70)))
```

I can't find any other clear instructions or solutions.  How do I enable word wrap in visual-line-mode?

Comment: `(global-visual-line-mode t)` is wrong; it should be `(global-visual-line-mode 1)`, no?

Comment: @jehad How would I know?  I can't find any information one way or the other.  I can change it, but I'm still left with the problem of setting the wrap width.

Comment: Perhaps there is a misunderstanding as to what `auto-fill-mode` does . . . it does not go through the buffer from top to bottom and fix everything -- instead, it works while the user is typing a particular line and affects only that particular line by inserting a new line based on the `fill-column` -- i.e., `\n`.  `visual-line-mode` does not alter the text of the file in any manner, but visually affects how the buffer is displayed by wrapping long lines that reach the edge of the window or right fringe.  Either `t` or `1` are both acceptable for toggling a minor-mode to the *on* position.

Comment: @lawlist There's almost certainly misunderstanding as to what `auto-fill-mode` does :)  I can't seem to find clear documentation anywhere on this or anything else related to Emacs.

Answer (score 1):

visual-line-mode only affects the display, whereas `fill-column` is about limiting the length of actual lines in the text.  Currently in Emacs you cannot control the visual wrapping other than by controlling your window's size.  This said, you can automate the control of the window's size.  E.g. with packages such as https://github.com/joostkremers/visual-fill-column which will play with the window margin settings to force visual wrapping at the column set in `visual-fill-column`.